# Android background location

Tags: java, android, service, geolocation

Good day, help an inexperienced person. I write mainly in C++, but it’s not very convenient to interact with Android, so I have to learn a new language. I'm writing an application in which I need to share location with a separate device. I've been looking for a way to implement background location detection for a long time. The examples from the Internet are very old and did not work on modern versions of Android. As a result, I was able to put together a working code, but I encountered the following problem: the phone gets very hot and the battery runs out pretty quickly, and the location icon blinks several times a second, although I don’t request location updates that often. Help me understand the problem, I think it will also be useful for other people on the Internet. The code is attached below. I am writing from a translator, so please forgive any inaccuracies.

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    Button btnStartService, btnStopService;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.logger);
        btnStartService = findViewById(R.id.sartPBN);
        btnStopService = findViewById(R.id.stopPBN);;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 3);
                textView.setText("Ok");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 2);
        }
        if (requestCode == 2 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 2);
        }
        if (requestCode == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            textView.setText("Ok");
        }
    }
    public void stopPBN_onClick(View view) {

    }

    public void sartPBN_onClick(View view) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

`LocationService`

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
        
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 10000)
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(10000)
                .build();

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationResult: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startForegroundService(intent);
        startLocationUpdates();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }
}
```